# Memory allocation of local variables within nested {}

Tags: c, scope, runtime, local-variables, compile-time

I have few queries on allocation of `var2` local variable, in reference to the below code.

1. When will the memory of a local variable `var2` allocated? Whether `var2` will be allocated whenever function is called or whenever condition is satisfied and control goes inside `if(Threshold > 5)`?
2. Does keeping `var2` within condition just only restrict the scope of local variable?
3. Does keeping `var2` within condition improve processing speed as variable is not allocated and de-allocated every time function is called?

```
void fun1(int Threshold)
{
    int var1 = 0;
    if(Threshold > 5)
    {
        int var2 = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on optimization level, the variable may never be allocated at all. An optimizing compiler can throw all unused variables away, as well as reuse the memory for two variables having non-overlapping lifetime.

Checking from assembler output (`gcc -S file.c`) one can often see all the used variables allocated immediately after the function entry:

```
 sub r1, $108   ;;  stack space needed for array[100] (and some)
```

corresponding to:

```
 void func(bool a)
 {
      if (a)
      {
           char array[100];
           subfunc(array, 100);
      } else {
           char array2[15];
           subfunc2(array2, 15);
      }
 }
```

Comment: I can think of cases, where dynamic variable allocation would be preferred -- e.g. recursive functions with low probability of allocating a huge chunk. So I would expect compilers to have options or attributes to control the compile-time allocation strategy.

Answer (score 1):

> *1. When will the memory of a local variable 'var2' allocated.*

The memory is mapped (*if the variable is allocated, i.e., variable does not get optimized out by the compiler*) at compile time. The stack is allocated when the program is loaded into memory. So, to speak strictly, it does not have any impact (cost) on the run-time.

> *2. Is keep 'var2' within condition just only restricts the scope of local variable.*

Right you are. `var2` scope is limited to the inner block only.

> *3. Whether keeping 'var2' within condition will improve processing speed as variable is not allocated and de-allocated every time function is called.*

Not related. Anyway this (variable definition) will be a compile time operation. Only the scope is changed based on the block of definition.

Comment: >At compile time. Optimizing compiler is free to generate code that will not allocate (not adjust stack register or reserve a general purpose register) a space for variable if condition is not met. When we speak about compile time allocation, we usually mean static storage in C terminology. This statement is somewhat correct, but misleading.

Comment: @user3125367 that is what I tried to make clear, by the _conditional_ statement. Can you propose a better wordings, if you have any suggestion, please?

Comment: @user3125367 you need not put a comment, you can directly [edit] my answer. :-)

Comment: "At runtime, but allocation is zero-cost in this case and may not occur when condition not met" — sml that I think, at least in OP perspective.

Comment: Hard wording, prefered to discuss ;)

Comment: @user3125367 Thanks for the feedback. Updated slightly. Is it ok now?

Comment: Thank you for comments. a) In example code I kept var2 just initialized but assume its been using. Then with C99 compiler by calling func() whether var2 memory will be allocated in stack even if the condition is not met or allocates memory in stack, only if condition is true.  b) May be based on compilers/chip set var2 may be allocated in stack or registers. My main intention for this query is whether memory/resource are allocated only if condition is true or irrespective of condition memory/resource are allocated when func() is called.